# How to force composer to install even with missing extensions?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am attempting to install phpspreadsheet via composer on my Mac running macOS 10.15.  I know that this version of macOS doesn't have the php zip extension so composer isn't installing the library.

The thing is, the library is going to wind up on a server that does have the zip extension.  So, I really don't need for the zip extension to be on my Mac. I just need the library installed so I can upload the vendor folder to the server.

How can I get composer to install it and ignore the extension check?  I don't have access to a shell on the server the site runs on so I can't install directly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the option `--ignore-platform-reqs`.

Be aware that the zip extension is also directly used for installation. If that fails, Composer will try to install the deps by cloning the repositories, but you would need to at least have `git` installed on the dev machine.

[The docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i).